# Add title in addition to data description in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am working on a jquery gallery and each image has a data description. I want to add a title above each data description. How can I do this? I cannot figure it out. Thanks. I am suspecting the variables need to be changed in the code snippet I posted below.

```
var $loader = $rgGallery.find('div.rg-loading').show();

                $items.removeClass('selected');
                $item.addClass('selected');

                var $thumb      = $item.find('img'),
                    largesrc    = $thumb.data('large'),
                    title       = $thumb.data('description');


                $('<img/>').load( function() {

                    $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image').empty().append('<img src="' + largesrc + '"/>');

                    if( title )
                        $rgGallery.find('div.rg-caption').show().children('p').empty().text( title );

                    $loader.hide();

                    if( mode === 'carousel' ) {
                        $esCarousel.elastislide( 'reload' );
                        $esCarousel.elastislide( 'setCurrent', current );
                    }

                    anim    = false;

                }).attr( 'src', largesrc );

            };

        return { init : init };

    })();

    Gallery.init();
});
```

Here's my html code in a js fiddle file: [jsfiddle.net/amw312/tq86nv7z/62/](http://jsfiddle.net/amw312/tq86nv7z/62/)

Comment: Can you show html for the gallery?

Comment: @Amy :D you can edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should set you on the correct path. Of course, I do not know if you want some special formatting. I see in your example, you already added data-title attribute. I just put the title inside the description block. You can seperate it out (remember to also make elem available. I just reduced typing by creating a local elem var).

```
        var $thumb      = $item.find('img'),
            largesrc    = $thumb.data('large'),
            description = $thumb.data('description');
            title       = $thumb.data('title');


        $('<img/>').load( function() {

            $rgGallery.find('div.rg-image').empty().append('<img src="' + largesrc + '"/>');

            if( description ){
                 var elem =  $rgGallery.find('div.rg-caption').show().children('p') 
                 elem.empty().text( description );

                 if(title)
                     elem.prepend(title + "<br />");
             }

            $loader.hide();
```

Comment: glad to help Amy.. just add a <strong> tag around the code, like so: elem.prepend("<strong>"+ title + "</strong><br />");